# Why is my index printing when I try to print the contents of the list?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to square the every digit in a number provided by the user. I am getting the correct output but I get an additional index at the end I'm not really sure why. I've put comments in my code to explain what I'm trying to do at every step. How do I get rid of that index on the end?

```
def square_digits(num):

    print(num)

    string_num =(str(num)) #convert the num to a string   

    for word in string_num: #iterate through every digit 

        word = int(word) #convert each digit to an int so we can square it
        square_num = word * word
        str_sq_num = list(str(square_num)) #create a list of those nums

        for count in str_sq_num:  #iterate through list to make it one number  
            print(count, end = "")  


    print(str_sq_num)
    return str_sq_num
```

So an example number is being given `3212`. I should output `9414`, instead my output is `9414['4']`. Another example is a number `6791`, the output should be `3649811`, but my output is `3649811['1']`.

Comment: `['4']` is coming from `print(str_sq_num)` at the end.

Comment: get rid of `print(str_sq_num)`

Comment: You're not getting an index, you're getting a list containing a single item, the string representation of the last digit in your number. Check what you're iterating over, and what you're assigning to `str_sq_num`

Comment: Each time through the `for` loop you set `str_sq_num` to a list of the digits in `square_num`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way for loops work in python. The variable `str_square_num` is left over from the last iteration of `for word in string_num`.

For example, assuming your number is 12, in the first iteration `str_square_num` will be `[1]`, or `1` squared. But this value is overriden in the second iteration, when it is set to `[4]`, or 2 squared. Thus the array will always contain only the square of the last digit.

If your goal is to get the array of all indicies, try this:

```
def square_digits(num):
    print(num)
    string_num =(str(num)) #convert the num to a string
    str_sq_num = []

    for word in string_num: #iterate through every digit 

        word = int(word) #convert each digit to an int so we can square it
        square_num = word * word
        str_sq_num.extend(str(square_num)) #create a list of those nums

    for count in str_sq_num:  #iterate through list to make it one number  
        print(count, end = "")  


    print(str_sq_num)
    return str_sq_num
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm not trying to return the array of the indices, I'm just trying to return a string of those output numbers, my main problem is just figuring out an effective way to return an output of just '9414' instead of '9414['4']. I am probably over complicating the problem anyways by creating a list to begin with but I am a beginner and that was the only way I could really think of implementing the solution to a problem like that.

Comment: You could use `''.join(list)` to convert a list to a astring

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but looking at your examples I suppose this should work:

```
def square_digits(num):
    print(num)

    string_num = (str(num))
    str_sq_num = []

    for word in string_num:
        word = int(word)
        square_num = word * word
        str_sq_num.append(square_num)
    for count in str_sq_num:
        print(count, end = "")

    return str_sq_num
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test it, but this should do it:

def square_digits(string_num):

```
return "".join([str(int(num)**2) for num in string_num])
```